# run error using MinGW with netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: c++, mingw, netbeans-7

I Installed MinGW and i'm using it with netbeans. However when i try to run a simple "Hello world" programm it gives me the following error:

```
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-     conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Notandi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/somegame'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1-   Windows/somegame.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Notandi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/somegame'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/somegame build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o -   lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2.dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output    file dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/somegame.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/somegame.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Notandi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/somegame'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Notandi/Documents/NetBeansProjects/somegame'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

I have checked if the program is running in background, but it isn't.
im using windows 64bit and using MinGW for c++.

Answer (score 0):

I simply configured NetBeans to use MinGW and faced the same inconveniences, but soon simply 
decided to use NetBeans with "Run as an administrator", which helped (and so even made "Run as an administrator" unnecessary in further runs). And on a next week I can reinstall MinGW + MSYS in another manner. I'm citing:

> The NetBeans IDE might have issues when you try to build and run projects later if MSYS is installed under a limited user account